# templateSelection arguments do not contain data from select2:select trigger params data

Tags: jquery-select2

### Bug reproduction

http://jsbin.com/dajexiraca/2/edit?html,js,console,output

### Issue

[The docs say you can trigger a select2:select event and pass data via params.data.](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2) However, my templateSelection code fails because additional data is missing. Consider the code sample below.

### Code

`` javascript
  // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
  $('#example1').trigger({
      type: 'select2:select',
      params: {
        data: {
          customData: "Hello World" // NOT AVAILABLE INSIDE templateSelection function!!!
        }
      }
  }); ``